# Magento-1.9 mage.js file issue with Google Adwords

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am new to Magento and here I am facing issue with Google AdWords. 
There is a script file which is causing the issue

> https://magentocore.net/mage/mage.js

when I am running in local this script file is not coming but in the server, this file is coming in all the pages.
I checked my project but didn't find the mage.js file and have no idea where it is coming from 
Please guide me on this ...
any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance ...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your site is hacked and somebody added the illustrous MagentoCore card and identity skimmer to the Misc Header/Footer section of your admin backend. You should have a developer or security analyst check your site for backdoors and missing patches.

See for specific instructions:

http://gwillem.gitlab.io/2018/08/30/magentocore.net_skimmer_most_aggressive_to_date/